# In javascript, how to convert Decimal (with decimal points) to Hexadecimal Strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert decimal value to hexadecimal string, but the decimal value has decimal point:

Decimal: 0.01
Hexadecimal: 3C23D70A

I couldn't figure out how to convert 0.01 to 3C23D70A in javascript, using .toString(16) simply returns 0. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Erm...`3C23D70A` is `1008981770`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value *3C23D70A* is in [IEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) Single Precision-format, in Big endian  with a mantissa of 23 bits.

You can see how it works [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Javascript doesn't have native support for this, but you can add it with this module: [IEE754](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ieee754)

Example of how to encode and decode:

```
const ieee754 = require('ieee754');

const singlePrecisionHex =
  {
    isLe:false, // Little or Big endian
    mLen:23, // Mantisa length in bits excluding the implicit bit
    nBytes:4, // Number of bytes
    stringify( value ) {
      const buffer = [];
      if (!(typeof value === 'number'))
        throw Error('Illegal value');
      ieee754.write( buffer, value, 0, this.isLe, this.mLen, this.nBytes );
      return buffer.map( x => x.toString(16).padStart(2,'0') ).join('').toUpperCase();
    },
    parse( value ) {
      if (!(typeof value === 'string' && value.length === (this.nBytes * 2)))
        throw Error('Illegal value');
      const buffer =
        value.match(/.{2}/g) // split string into array of strings with 2 characters
        .map( x => parseInt(x, 16));
      return ieee754.read( buffer, 0, this.isLe, this.mLen, this.nBytes );
    }
  }


const encoded = singlePrecisionHex.stringify(0.01);
const decoded = singlePrecisionHex.parse(encoded);
console.log(encoded);
console.log(decoded);
```

Comment: Any chance you have used this module before? I couldn't get 3C23D70A from 0.01. Am i doing this right?  ieee754.write(Buffer.from("0.01"), 0.01, 0, 0, 0,4)

Comment: Thanks, works as expected. Can you tell me why in (buffer, value, offset, isLE, mLen, nBytes), how did you know isLE is false?

Comment: @Jay I updated the answer with an object that can both encode and decode a the value. I didn't know if it was in Little Endian or Big Endian, so I tried both. It is just the order of the bytes, so it is either 3C23D70A or 0AD7233C. First I tried with mantissa length 24, but got the wrong result. I changed it to 23 and got the correct result (probably because it is zero based)

Comment: I see. For the mantissa length i understand it's 23 according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/type-float?view=vs-2019. Anyway, thanks again for your help!

Comment: The correct length is 23. I misunderstood the table I was looking at. The number in the table included the implicit bit, but that is not stored in the binary representation.

Comment: @Jay Updated the object, using "constants" so the same value is used both for encoding and decoding (which I renamed to stringify and parse).